# Comparar dato de un textbox con los datos de un .txt

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion la cual va guardando diferentes números de partes (txt.Nparte) en un archivo .txt, lo que que me esta fallando y no he podido hacer que funcione es que cuando le de click al botón guardar primero compara el número de parte nuevo en el archivo de texto, si ya existe mandará un mensaje, de lo contrario lo guardará.

Para llamar las funciones:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Leer_datos();
        //crear_excel();
        Guardar_datos();            
    }
```

Para guardar los datos hago lo siguiente:

```
    public void Guardar_datos()
    {
        Pieza = "";
        Gasket_up = "";
        Gasket_down = "";
        Rejilla = "";
        Tela = "";
        Etiqueta = "";
        Clamp = "";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtN_parte.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingresar numero de parte");
            return;
        }
        if (cBPieza.Checked == true)
            Pieza = cBPieza.Text;
        else
            Pieza = "N/A";
        if (cBGasket_up.Checked == true)
            Gasket_up = cBGasket_up.Text;
        else
            Gasket_up = "N/A";
        if (cbGasket_down.Checked == true)
            Gasket_down = cbGasket_down.Text;
        else
            Gasket_down = "N/A";
        if (cbRejilla.Checked == true)
            Rejilla = cbRejilla.Text;
        else
            Rejilla = "N/A";
        if (cBTela.Checked == true)
            Tela = cBTela.Text;
        else
            Tela = "N/A";
        if (cBTela.Checked == true)
            Tela = cBTela.Text;
        else
            Tela = "N/A";
        if (cBEtiqueta.Checked == true)
            Etiqueta = cBEtiqueta.Text;
        else
            Etiqueta = "N/A";
        if (cBClamp.Checked == true)
            Clamp = cBClamp.Text;
        else
            Clamp = "N/A";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTorque.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ingresar dato de torque");
            return;
        }

string[] lineas = { txtN_parte.Text, Pieza, Gasket_up, Gasket_down, Rejilla, Tela, Etiqueta, Clamp, txtTorque.Text };

StreamWriter outputFile = File.AppendText(@"C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt");
{
    foreach (string linea in lineas) {
        outputFile.WriteLine(linea);
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Registro exitoso");
    outputFile.Close();
    return;
}
```

y se guardan en el archivo .txt en esta secuencia identificando cada uno de los checkbox que se marcaron:

```
1

PIEZA

N/A

N/A

N/A

N/A

N/A

N/A

1
```

Para leer el archivo y comparar el número de parte hago lo siguiente:

```
public void Leer_datos()
{ 
    StreamReader leer = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt");
    string leer_linea;
    leer_linea = leer.ReadToEnd();
    if(leer_linea == txtN_parte.Text) {
        MessageBox.Show("Numero de parte ya existe");
    }                
    leer.Close();
}
```

Esta parte del codigo es la que no e logrado hacer funcionar.

Comment: En la primer parte parece que falta algo

Comment: Es la parte donde se declaran las variables de cada parametro que se incluyen en el numero de parte: deteccion de pieza, etiqueta, etc.

Comment: Coloca esa parte, será más fácil reproducir tu escenario :D

Comment: Listo @fredyfx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece que estas leyendo todo el archivo y lo estas comparando con el valor del texto de numero de parte.

Prueba usando el split con el salto de linea de la siguiente forma:

```
 public void Leer_datos(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader leer = new StreamReader(@"C:\\Users\\OsIbarra\\Documents\\TEST\\ejemplo.txt");
        string leer_linea;
        string[] separador = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] datos;
        leer_linea = leer.ReadToEnd();
        datos = leer_linea.Split(separador, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //validamos que tenemos datos y que el primer valor no sea igual al del textbox
        if (datos.Count() > 0 && datos[0] == txtN_parte.Text)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("Numero de parte ya existe");
        }else if(datos.Count() > 8) //validamos que tenga mas de un arreglo 9 lugares
        {

            for(int i=9;i<datos.Count();i+=9)
            {
                if (datos[i] == txtN_parte.Text)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Numero de parte ya existe");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }



        leer.Close();
    }
```

Con esto estarias leyendo siempre la posicion 1 para cada arreglo, esto depende del numero de campos que tienes en este caso estar leyendo cada 9 posiciones cuando tienes mas de un arreglo de cada uno de tus arreglos.

Saludos espero te sea util.

Comment: como comentas y ya lo probe si funciona para leer solo el primer arreglo, en este caso se pueden tener hasta 20 de ser necesario, ya no funcionaria para los siguientes numeros de parte captutados.

Comment: Entiendo, editare la respuesta para ponerte una propuesta rapida que se me ocurre.

Comment: ya probe el codigo y si realiza la busqueda en todo el archivo e indica si ya existe, lo unico es que ahora despues de marcar que ya existe de todos modos lo guarda..  estoy trabajando en esta sentencia para que no se ejecute el de guarda. Agregue el codigo en la descripcion.

Comment: ya quedo resuelto, en vez de utilizar funciones separadas para leer y guardar, se esta realizando la lectura y escritura en una sola y con eso funciono.